# How array type assignment works?

Tags: arrays, delphi, variable-assignment

I have the following code:

```
type
  PSuperListItem = ^TSuperListItem;
  TSuperListItem = record
    SubItems  : array of String;
    Marked    : Boolean;
    ImageIndex: Integer;
  end;

  TSuperListItems = array of PSuperListItem;

  TMyList = class(TCustomControl)
  public
   Items, ItemsX : TSuperListItems;
   procedure SwapItemLists;
  end;

procedure TMyList.SwapItemLists;
var tmp:TSuperListItems;
begin
 tmp:=Items; Items:=ItemsX; ItemsX:=tmp;
end;
```

I want to know if I've done correctly the assingtions from `SwapItemLists`. What happends when I assign `Items` to `tmp` ? Will be created a new copy of `Items` or will be passed just the pointer of that variable ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dynamic arrays are reference types. Which means that you have simply swapped references. The contents of the arrays are not copied.

Key to being able to answer this sort of question yourself is an understanding of what it means to be a reference type. In the case of a dynamic array, the variable of dynamic array type holds a reference to the array. That is implemented behind the scenes by means of the dynamic array variable being a pointer to the array.

Consider this code:

```
var
  a, b: TArray<Integer>;
....
a := TArray<Integer>.Create(42);
b := a;
b[0] := 666;
Assert(a[0] = 666);
Assert(@a[0] = @b[0]);
```

In this code, there is only ever one array. Both variables `a` and `b` refer to the same instance of that array.

In order to make a copy of a dynamic array, use the [`Copy`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Copy) function from the `System` unit.

Other examples of reference types include class instance variables, interface variables, anonymous methods and strings. These all behave similarly to dynamic arrays with the exception of strings.

Strings implement copy-on-write. This means that if a string object has more than one reference to it, modifications via a reference result in a copy being made at the point of modification. This has the effect of making the string data type behave semantically like a value type. In effect, when you use assignment with strings, that assignment is semantically indistguishable from copying. But the actual implementation of the copying of the string is postponed until it is needed, as an optimization.

Comment: Maybe nitpicking, but I think that your statement about the assignment of strings may be confusing for future readers: You say that assignment is performed by copying the string and then you continue that copying is postponed until needed. So, future readers may wonder when the string is actually copied.

Comment: @iamjoosy Fair point. I tried a re-word. What I'm trying to get at is that from the programmers point of view, strings behave as though they are values, but the implementation is reference with COW. In broad terms you don't need to know about the implementation and if you thing of strings as though they are values, then your mental model will match behaviour.